# Align div in li as center

Tags: html, css

Here is the fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/5jnnutg8/

My question is how can I align the "something #" list items as center and inline. One can see the "Hi" title is aligned in the center using `text-align: center` in css, but this doesn't seem to work for the list items.

Is there a pure css way of doing this without messing around with the `<div>`, `<ul>`, and `<li>` structure, as I am using a plugin for wordpress and it would be a pain to change this.

I want it to be that the "something #" list items are centered aligned, and if the browser is resized the "something 3" drops down but is still centered -- hope that makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `float: left`, simply use  `display: inline-block;`

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Working demo

```css
.list-holder {
  background: black;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
}
.div-list-item {
  background: red;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.ul-class {
  list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

a {
    display: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-holder">
  Hi
  <ul class="ul-class">
    <li class="li-class">
      <div class="div-list-item">
        Something 1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li-class">
      <div class="div-list-item">
        Something 2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="li-class">
      <div class="div-list-item">
        Something 3
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```